# How to leave a community / delete membership of a particular community?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Is it possible for a user to leave a specific community?

Obviously it's possible to just not log in to the community, but is it possible to not be counted as a member of a particular community any more?

Comment: Sure, you can check out any time you like .. but you can never leave :) In all seriousness, what you need to do is request for your account to be deleted. See the duplicate link.